Number Guessing Game I would like to display the number of guesses in the final message
When guessing the number correctly I am displayed Congratulations! You guessed the correct number! then the program exits after 5 seconds
I was expecting the number of guesses to be displayed at the end of the game
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int answer = 0; //Define answer as an integer
    int guesses = 1; //Define guesses as an integer
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); //Seed the random number generator
    int random_number = rand() % 100; //Generate a random number between 0 and 100
    printf("Welcome to the number guessing game!\n");
    printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100:\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);   //Get the user's guess
while (answer != random_number) {   //While the user's guess is not equal to the random number
    if (answer < 1 || answer > 100) { //If the user's guess is out of range
        printf("Your guess is out of range. Try again.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100:\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        guesses++;  //Increment the number of guesses
    } else if (answer < random_number) {    //If the user's guess is too low
        printf("Your guess is too low. Try again.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100:\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        guesses++; 
    } else if (answer > random_number) {    //If the user's guess is too high
        printf("Your guess is too high. Try again.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 0 and 100:\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        guesses++;
    }
}
if (answer == random_number) { //If the user's guess is equal to the random number
                printf("Congratulations! You guessed the correct number in %d tries.\n", guesses);
                sleep(5); //Wait for 5 seconds
                return 0;
            }   
} 


Does not reproduce for me; the program prints, for example, “Congratulations! You guessed the correct number in 8 tries.” Make sure you have saved the file from the editor buffer and are compiling the source code you want to compile.

With the code you show, the loop will only end when answer == random_number (which means that if (answer == random_number) is not needed). Then you will print the number of guesses, followed by your program waiting for five seconds and then exiting. Which is basically the behavior you describe. What is really wrong with your program?

Can't reproduce. Perhaps your system needs fflush(stdout) before sleep().

Note that int random_number = rand() % 100; forms a value [0...99] and not as suggested by comment //Generate a random number between 0 and 100.

On a different note, there are three lines of code that is common in all three cases inside the loop. That means they could be put after the checks, so you don't have them duplicated three times.

Thanks guys yeah I was doing something wrong and running off of C/C++ Runner which was causing my program to not display the tries it is working now thanks a lot
